# Code inside of a comment is causing compile failure - Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

This may seem odd, but text in a comment is causing my code to not compile.  (This is decompiled code; I don't format it like this normaly).

The comment (at the very end of the file; added automatically by the decompiler):

```
/* Location:           C:\Pokechu22\TestServer\plugins\uSkyBlock.jar

 * Qualified Name:     us.talabrek.ultimateskyblock.uSkyBlock

 * JD-Core Version:    0.7.0.1

 */
```

Here's an image of what it looks like in eclipse.

[image: Image of the oddness]

Here are the exact error messages (and these are the ONLY error messages, and are all in that one comment):

```
    Description                                  Resource       Path                                                    Location        Type  
    Core cannot be resolved to a type            uSkyBlock.java /SO_UnicodeEscapeError/src/us/talabrek/ultimateskyblock line 2009       Java Problem  
    Invalid unicode                              uSkyBlock.java /SO_UnicodeEscapeError/src/us/talabrek/ultimateskyblock line 2005       Java Problem  
    Qualified cannot be resolved to a type       uSkyBlock.java /SO_UnicodeEscapeError/src/us/talabrek/ultimateskyblock line 2007       Java Problem
```

The error for `plugins` is eclipse complaining about a typo: `The word 'plugins' is not correctly spelled`.

This is easy for me to resolve - I can just delete that comment - but why would this be happening?  Shouldn't code in comments be completely ignored?

---

EDIT: As an additional note, all of the errors are inside of the comment block, and removal of the comment block allows the code to compile.  That's not the question here.  My question is why does java care about the text in the comment at all here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the string `\u` is interpreted by Eclipse as the prefix of a unicode character, while here it is just a part of a filename in a comment. The only ways to remove this error are either to remove the `\u` part, for example by replacing it with `&#92;u` if it is to be shown in a javadoc, or to escape the backslash character: `\\u`.

Note that it is a known "bug" of Eclipse, see: [Bug 6677](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=6677) [Bug 10753](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10753)

This behaviour is consistent with the Java specs though, as Java comments can contain unicode characters:

> Except for comments, identifiers, and the contents of character and
>   string literals, all input elements in a program are formed only from
>   ASCII characters (or Unicode escapes which result in ASCII
>   characters).

[§3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)

Comment: Well, that makes some sense.  It's an annoying behavior though.

Comment: At least it's a known bug (though they seem not to care).  So I'm not the only one who's had an issue like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a copy paste block of code which has a unicode characters that is not readable by the eclipse, try to delete it and rewrite it yourself

Comment: That's not the issue - the code compiles when that one comment is removed.  I can get it to compile; I'm just confused as to why java even cares about the code in that comment and is causing three errors.

Comment: The two errors concerning Qualified and Core  are just warning that could compile your code successfully with them, the problem only with the invalid unicode which is not readable for the eclipse even inside a comment